# Twitter Image sharing for web applications (API?)

Tags: javascript, image, twitter, web, sharing

Hello I am making a web application in which users will have to upload images they take to twitter using an integrated twitter image sharing button or function. I have looked at the TwitPic API, which does namely that, but according to their website (https://blog.twitpic.com/2014/10/twitpics-future/) they are basically discontinuing the it.

My Question is if there is an API or way in which I can have users share their image to twitter from within a browser window (so that i can be done via mobile devices as well)?

So far I have just used the twitter button creator and created a normal tweet share, but it does not support image sharing or I cannot seem to figure out how to make it support image sharing.

Comment: Will these users be logged in to Twitter? Will they have gone through OAuth with your app?

Comment: probably both will be necessary, but im more likely to need to run them through OAuth the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at the [Twitter documentation for uploading images](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media).

Every modern Twitter library will be able to do this for you.

Comment: I have read through this now and it has given me a slightly better understanding of what I need to do, however I am still unsure as to exactly which API will allow me to upload pictures/updates (do I need to use and oauth API or a twitter one and the documentation on the twitter API isn't very good.

Comment: the examples go over the twurl command line tool, which isn't particularly enlightening. There are a lot of references to the POST media/update endpoint, but everything there is about .json, which I am not very familiar with.

Comment: If you can update the question with more details about which library you're using, or some code you've written, I can give a more detailed answer.